# Подскажите название темы в VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

Как называется такая сине-голубо-красная тема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стандартная "Темная+" (Dark+ или как-то так): https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUxfp.png